# Symfony2 FOS User not a valid entity

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

im not sure what ive done wrong here.

I am following the instruction on how to install the fos bundle and have come across a problem.

I am getting the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'Class
>   RS\Entity\User is not a valid entity or mapped super class.' in
>   PATH\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException.php:142

My user class is in `/src/RS/Entity/User.php`

And i have`'RS' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/reportsuite/src'`in `app/autoload.php`

The class is

```
<?php
// /src/RS/Entity/User.php

namespace RS\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

As far as i can tell this is a mapped entity, unless im missing something?

Ive also tried creating the entity in by bundle and another bundle like `Acme/UserBundle/Entity/User.php`

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:       default
        connections:
            default:
                dbname:           axpdb
                user:             %database_user%
                password:         %database_password%
                host:             %database_host%
                port:             %database_port%
                charset:          UTF8
            reportsuite:
                dbname:           reportsuite
                user:             %database_user%
                password:         %database_password%
                host:             %database_host%
                port:             %database_port%
                charset:          UTF8
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection:       default
                mappings:
                    ReportSuiteMainMenuBundle: ~
            reportsuite:
                connection:       reportsuite
                mappings:


# Security
jms_security_extra:
    secure_controllers:  true
    secure_all_services: false

# FOS User Config
#fos_user:
#    db_driver: orm
#    firewall_name: main
#    user_class: RS\Entity\User
#    model_manager_name: reportsuite
```

I have 2 databases that I need to access and I have commented out the fos stuff so i can continue working.

Comment: Could you paste the `doctrine:` entry from your `config.yml`? I suspect you have not configured your mapping correctly. (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636144/integrating-bundles-related-doctrine-2-entities-in-symfony-2-and-coupling/8637640#8637640)

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using the default bundle structure?

Comment: The project is dynamic where customers can drag/drop custom modules in and out of the system. So I put the code in RS/ that is global to all the modules. Unless this is the wrong approach? I'm used to working with Zend Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Did You checkd a namespace ?

I think it should be:

```
namespace Namespace\YourBundle\Entity
```

You can use entites from all of Your bundles.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
touch Entity/*
```

and you are OK.

Answer (score -1):

Had this problem - don't forget the annotation `* @ORM\Entity` like below:

```
/**
 * Powma\ServiceBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
```